# how to get client side path of the uploded file

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form that uploads files, i need to get client side path to file?
server path i could get from php array $_FILES

```
$_FILES["UploadFileName"]["tmp_name"]
```

how to get client side path to file stored on a client computer?

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File to upload : <input type ="file" name = "UploadFileName"></p><br />
    <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Press THIS to upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Why not scan their whole file tree while you get the file paths it... seems legit!

Comment: At best you can get the original filename, but you will not be allowed to get the entire file path.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. That's a security matter and the browsers will not provide that to you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. [This part](https://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/it_handbuch/18_001.html#dodtp4c22d0a4-6476-4353-9c42-412a314d672c) of a German open book had me worried for a sec: "name: ursprünglicher Pfad und Dateiname der Datei auf dem Clientrechner" (Translation: "name: original path and file name of the file on the client machine")

Answer (score 2):

> How to get client side path to file stored on a client computer?

It is **not allowed** for security reasons.If this were possible, an attacker could gain information regarding how files/folders were structured on a client computer. Any **fully trusted code** on users' machine can do that. So your goal is to convince user to install something that will provide you with the information.

For Windows (all require installation of some sort):

- ActiveX controls
- Native EXE
- Locally installed managed EXE
- locally installed HTA for IE only