# fakepath for uploading file html-python

Tags: python, html, file-upload

I have this file input:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file_id" />
```

and I want to upload a file from local machine (`C:\my_file.xls`) to the server, but the problem is when I want to upload the file.

It has writen a fakepath to the file and I have got this message when uploading:

```
No such file or directory: u'C:\\fakepath\\my_file.xls'
```

I knew that it has relation with browser security feature, and I have tried to make some solutions for that like creating a folder with the name `fakepath` or delete this word from the given path...

Is there an other (elegant or efficient) way to get file's local full path in the input (the real path) for the file ?

Comment: May be you provide some server code?

Comment: @DenisNikanorov Actually, the server code concerne just getting the xls file and read it with xlrd library for python and retrieve data, but didn't localize the file (error message in the post)

Comment: Depends on the browser, but if you're uploading via `<input type="file"...`, why would you need the full path?

Comment: @Aya to localize the file, even in Firefox it get just fileName but when sending to the server it dosn't know the file

Comment: @Drwhite Not sure what you mean by "localize the file". Is the idea that the 'server' runs on the same machine as the browser, and you want the server to be able to open the file from the local disk?

Comment: @Aya: the apps is running in localhost and YES, i want that the server will be able to open the file from the local disk but file is in C:\  directory (`C:\my_file.xls`) but the server return error says `No such file or directory: u'C:\\fakepath\\my_file.xls'`

Comment: @Drwhite Well, using an HTML form doesn't sound like a good fit for what you're trying to achieve. Why did you decide to use HTML rather than some other interface (e.g. a console app or a proper GUI with Tkinter or wxPython)?

Comment: actually, i have tried to add an attribute to the form (`enctype= multipart/form-data`) it allows to send the file (as object) in the input instead of its URL, and i will be back later to post the solution for other posts like this one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually get the file path [from the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14915470/344286). That just wont work.

You have to change how you think - the client is completely separate from the server. What you do on one is only partially related to the other (and good thing, too!)

What you  need to do is decide where on your **server** you want to store files. And then put them there. If you want to be able to download the files that have been uploaded, you have to decide who can access the files, how you're going to list them, etc.

But these should be completely unrelated to the information you get from the client - the only thing you should get from the client is the data contained in the file (and maybe a filename).