# how to get client uploading file path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

[image] this is my choose file for uploading popup,i tried to get uploading file path form client to server side.

> but IE display original client path file like(C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg) but other browser's displaying fake path like (C:\fakepath\Desert.jpg)
>
> this is my part of code.I don't know how to get file full path name form client side,but one think i know it's secure purpose so some browser not display full path name but how IE display?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing File Upload Inputs</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function doTest(form) {
        window.frames.myframe.location = form.elements.myfile.value;
      }
      
      function showSrc() {
        alert(window.frames.myframe.location);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get" action="#" onsubmit="doTest(this); return false;">
      <input type="file" name="myfile" size="30">
      <input type="submit" value="Test">
      <input type="button" onclick="showSrc();" value="Show">
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="">
    </form>
    <iframe src="#" width="300" height="300" frameborder="1" name="myframe"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you require the client image path?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14915470/3081659

Comment: You can't for security reasons. IE shouldn't give you that much information in the first place.